# How to duplicate UIView infinite times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my app, there is a portion that has to be repeated during a button press. That is, a UIView, that has a couple of text fields, that should repeat infinitely as long as a button is pressed,. To better understand it, I am uploading a "demo view" of the page and the code I used to implement it. I was able to duplicate the view and the label, but the UIButton is not repeated.[image: First Image, with the button name "Repeat"]
[image: Second Image. Label- "Here" has appeared but the button has not]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _testView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [_testView addSubview:_labelRef];
    [_testView addSubview:_buttonRef];
    [self.view addSubview:_testView];
    _lastView=_testView;
        _archievedData=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_testView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)repeatButton:(id)sender {

    UIView *newView=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:_archievedData];
    CGRect newFrame;
    newFrame.origin.x=newView.frame.origin.x;
    newFrame.origin.y=(newView.frame.origin.y + newView.bounds.size.height);
    newFrame.size.height=newView.frame.size.height;
    newFrame.size.width=newView.frame.size.width;
    newView.frame=newFrame;
    newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
    _archievedData=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newView];
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: if you are using constraints check button constraints

Comment: I added the button in the storyboard

Comment: seems your button is adding but frame is not sufficient to display button name

Comment: I have placed a breakpoint at the button's action. it goes there when the button in view 1 is pressed, but its not called when the second view button is clicked. Even when both the views exist, when the first button is clicked, it goes to the break point

Comment: test once without changing frame for the new view. just add it to view. see fi this works.

Comment: it doesnt work. When the new view appears, the button stops working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84357/discussion-between-sidharth-j-dev-and-naresh).

Comment: in viewDidLoad the view is probably not "layed out" yet: it's frame is not valid. so the `whole newFrame.origin.x=newView.frame.origin.x; ... ` section should be written like `whole newFrame.origin.x=self.frame.origin.x; ... `. if you are not using autolayout of course...